# .htaccess folder redirects without redirecting from source tags

Tags: php, .htaccess, audio, encryption, directory

Ok so I have a problem, and from my research so far, it is impossible. Hopefully someone will tell me it's possible.

I have a folder with music. On other pages, I am using audio tags with source tags linking to the folder's music.

I want people to be able to listen to the music from my webpage via the tags, but not go directly to the directory and listen to the music. Is this possible?

Comment: If you have a public file anybody can access it. If you link to the file with the src attr of your audio tag it is the same as the user copies the url and access it directly. You cannot distinguish between both from server side.

Comment: Put an .htaccess in the music folder with `Options -Indexes`, this will prevent Apache from generating a file list. Users can still access the music files if they know the filename.

Comment: It is possible to generate a unique md5 secret which allows a user to access the track once. It should be generated when the user loads your site. Then you do not link the file directly but a php file which validates the secret, send the file and sets the secret invalid for later use. Do deny from all in .htaccess so the file could only be loaded from php. but this is a php solution, not .htaccess.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought. Oh well I'll just have to get clever!